# Wedderburn theorem for finite-dimensional algebras over the complex numbers

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

I'm trying to understand how to apply the Wedderburn theorem in the context of unitary algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ that are finite-dimensional and semisimple. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with dimension $d$. I have the following questions:

1. It can be shown that there is an algebra monomorphism between $\mathcal{A}$ and the full-matrix algebra $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. My intuition behind this is that we can "reduce" the problem of studying finite dimensional algebras to that of studying subalgebras of $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. Is this a correct intuiton?
2. If we assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is semi-simple, we can prove that it is isomorphic to a direct sum of full-matrix algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ (using the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and then applying the Wedderburn Theorem), i.e., we can say that $\mathcal{A}$ is isomorphic to a set of block-diagonal matrices. Now if we fix $n$ and consider an arbitrary semi-simple subalgebra $\mathcal{B}$ of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, from what I understand this doesn't necessarily imply that $\mathcal{B}$ is in a block-diagonal form, or even that there is a basis that simultaneously puts all matrices in $\mathcal{B}$ in block-diagonal form. Is this correct? Also, I do know that if $\mathcal{B}$ is commutative and closed under conjugate-transposition, then we can find a basis that simultaneously diagonalizes all matrices, but is this the only case where it happens?
3. In the applications I'm currently studying (coherent algebras and association schemes), showing that an algebra is semisimple is only used to prove that we can decompose the identity as a sum of idempotents. Are there any interesting applications of this theorem where other consequences are used?

Comment: For (1), yes, but that's like saying that one can reduce the study of arbitrary groups to the study of subgroups of symmetric groups For (2), let $\mathcal A$ be a full matrix algebra, and $\mathcal B$ the subalgebra generated by any diagonalizable but non-diagonalized matrix.  (As I understand your question, that means the answer to "Is this correct?" is "yes."  I'm not sure what the aswer to "why?" could be.)  For (3), I'm not sure that there's a strict linear order on facts about the Wedderburn theorem, so perhaps this is a big-list question asking for people's favourite applications?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks! Regarding (1) do you mean that this reduction isn't particularly useful? And regarding (3) the question is indeed poorly posed, I'll edit and turn it into a big-list question just out of curiosity.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463549/wedderburn-theorem-for-finite-dimensional-algebras-over-the-complex-numbers#comment1203528_463549), for (1), yes, that is what I mean: it is a pleasant theoretical result, but not too useful precisely because there is such a rich subalgebra structure of even the simplest algebras.

Comment: @LSpice I've got another question regarding (2). In your example, the subalgebra generated by any diagonalizable but non-diagonalized matriz A
 is not in block-diagonal form but is semisimple, but in the case where A
 is hermitian this algebra is a commutative ∗
-algebra, and so we can find a basis that simultaneously diagonalizes all of its matrices. Are there any examples where there isnt a basis that puts the semisimple algebra in block-diagonal form? Or can we always do this?

Comment: You can always put a semisimple matrix algebra into block-diagonal form over an algebraically closed field. This follows from the classification of the representations of a semisimple algebra: they are all direct sums of irreps, and each irrep is the standard d-dimensional module for $M_d(F)$, where $M_d(F)$ is one of the direct summands of the algebra.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463549/wedderburn-theorem-for-finite-dimensional-algebras-over-the-complex-numbers#comment1203545_463549), I think that the question is more interesting: not whether $A$ in itself is a sum of matrix algebras, but whether a semisimple subalgebra of $M_d(F)$ (with $F$ algebraically closed) may be conjugated within $M_d(F)$ into a direct sum of matrix algebras.  Probably this is well known, and maybe can even be deduced formally from the result you cite, but I think that there is at least a little new content.

Comment: @LSpice: I understood that. The results about representations I mentioned imply block-diagonalizability of any semisimple subalgebra of $M_d(F)$ into blocks each of which is a full matrix algebra on its own, though some blocks can be repeated. If you think there is a little new content I can spell out the details in an actual answer.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463549/wedderburn-theorem-for-finite-dimensional-algebras-over-the-complex-numbers#comment1203547_463549), oh, I see.  I read carelessly and thought you were just stating the abstract structure result, but now I see that you were applying it to the $d$-dimensional representation coming from $A \subseteq M_d(F)$.

Comment: @Joshua Grochow Could you elaborate as to why these results imply block-diagonalizability for any semisimple subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $M_d(F)$? I've been trying to formally prove this explicitly decomposing $F^d$ as a direct sum of $\mathcal{A}$-submodules, but so far I haven't been able to create such modules from the algebra isomorphism between $A$ and its Wedderburn Decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elaborating as an answer b/c the OP asked for more details that didn't fit into a comment]

Suppose $\mathcal{A} \subseteq M_d(F)$ with $F$ algebraically closed and $\mathcal{A}$ semisimple. To keep things clear, let me refer to the inclusion map as $\varphi \colon \mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow M_d(F)$, which is thus a $d$-dimensional representation of $\mathcal{A}$. Let $M \cong F^d$ denote the corresponding $\mathcal{A}$-module.

As an algebra, there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{A} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathcal{A}_i$, where there are integers $d_i$ such that $A_i \cong M_{d_i}(F)$ for all $i$. (I've written it this seemingly verbose way to keep track of possibly distinct summands that may have the same dimension.) But this does not a priori guarantee that the representation $\varphi$ (or, equivalently, its image) is block-diagonalizable.

However, as $\mathcal{A}$ is a semisimple algebra, all of its representations are semisimple, and thus are direct sums of irreps. Equivalently, the module $M$ is a direct sum of simple modules.

Now, there are precisely $k$ simple modules of $\mathcal{A}$; if we denote the $i$-th one by $M_i$, then $\dim_F(M_i) = d_i$, and the way $\mathcal{A}$ acts on $M_i$ is that for $j \neq i$, $\mathcal{A}_j$ acts by 0 on $M_i$, while $\mathcal{A}_i \cong M_{d_i}(F)$ acts on $M_i$ in its natural action on $F^{d_i} \cong M_i$.

Thus, by semisimplicity, there are integers $e_i$ such that, as $\mathcal{A}$-modules, $M \cong_{\mathcal{A}} \bigoplus_{i=1}^k M_i^{\oplus e_i}$. (The original representation $\varphi$ being faithful is equivalent to $e_i \geq 1$ for all $i$.) If we now choose a basis for $F^d$ that is a union of bases for each copy of $M_i$ appearing in the preceding decomposition, then in that basis the image of $\varphi$ is block-diagonal, with $e_i$ blocks of size $d_i \times d_i$, for each $i$. Furthermore, each $\mathcal{A}_i$ appears in these blocks in its diagonal embedding into $\bigoplus_{j=1}^{e_i} M_{d_i}(F)$.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the language of representation theory, so sorry if this question is obvious, but shouldn't $M = \mathcal{A}F^d$? Since 
 the unit of $\mathcal{A}$ isn't necessarily the identity matrix, I don't undestand why $F^d$ would be a $\mathcal{A}$-module. If so, can we apply te same argument to $\mathcal{A}F^d$ and then complete a basis in order to obtain the block-diagonalization?

Comment: Correction: by $\mathcal{A}F^d$ I mean the image of the unit in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes that's a potential issue but you already found the solution. Really what's happening in that case is that A is conjugate to matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and so is essentially a subalgebra of a smaller matrix algebra  acting on a smaller vector space. And then the rest of what I wrote goes through in that smaller matrix algebra & smaller vector space.

Comment: An alternative if perhaps less standard way to see it is to not require \varphi nor A-modules to be unital, and then we have to allow the 0 representation as a simple module.